# Why an implement of immutable trait can be mutable?

Tags: rust, traits, ownership, mutability

Here is my code, it can compile

```rust
trait AppendBar {
    fn append_bar(self) -> Self;
}

impl AppendBar for Vec<String> {
    fn append_bar(mut self) -> Self {
        self.push("Bar".to_string());
        self
    }
```

although it takes the ownership, but why it can mutate self in its implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because mutability of arguments is not part of the function signature.

This ...

```
fn foo(self) { ... }
```

... looks exactly the same from the outside as ...

```
fn foo(mut self) { ... }
```

... because it's not the caller's business what happens with the arguments once control transfers to the function.

Therefore, the implementation of the trait is allowed because the signature is effectively the same from the perspective of the caller.

---

Put another way, what is the difference between these two functions?

```
fn foo(mut v: String) {
    // ...
}

fn foo(v: String) {
    let mut v = v; // Rebind v as mutable.
    // ...
}
```

The answer is that there is none.  The `String` value was given to the function, so it can always mutate it.  If it helps you to understand what is going on, you could consider the first example to be a "shortcut" for the second, but they wind up meaning the same thing.

---

Note this is not a unique thing to Rust; in C++, `const`-ness of function arguments is not part of the function's signature, either.

Comment: but by default it's immutable, then why does it look same as mutable from the outside?

Comment: @Alexis Because, as I said, what the function does with the arguments isn't the caller's business. It might mutate them or it might not, but the caller doesn't need to know either way.

Comment: so when a function receiving a reference, & and &mut is different signatures?

Comment: @dpr Yes, because in that case it _is_ the caller's business; in the `&mut` case the function can alter state of a value it does not own, which is something the caller might need to concern itself with. Lifetimes also come into play there.

Comment: Or in other words, `&T` and `&mut T` are different _types_, but `T` and `mut T` are merely different _binding modes_. The former is important to the caller, since the types must match; the latter isn't, since the binding mode can be changed freely